# Confirming solution for finding value of $a$ for solutions to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

I'm doing the following question here:

> Let M=$\left( 
>     \begin{array}{ccc|c}
>         1 & 1 & 3a+1 & 2-3a \\
>         2 & a & 2 & -8\\
>        -1 & -1 & a^2-2a-3 & a^2
>     \end{array}
> \right)$.
> Find the values of $a$, $a \in \mathbb{R},$ such that:
> i) The system has infinitely many solutions.
> ii) The system has no solution.
> iii) The system has an unique solution.

So I row reduced the matrix until I got this:

$\left( 
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 1 & 3a+1 & 2-3a \\
        0 & a-2 & -6a & 6a-12\\
        0 & 0 & a^2+a-2 & a^2-3a+2
    \end{array}
\right)$.

i) There will be infinitely many solutions if we have a non pivot column (A free variable).

This means $a^2+a-2 = a^2-3a+2$. Solving, this gives $a=1$.

ii) There is no solution if $a^2+a-2=0$ but  $a^2-3a+2 \neq 0.$ Solving, we get $(a-1)(a+2)=0$ or $a=1,-2$ for the first equation and $(a-2)(a-1) \neq 0$ or $a\neq 2,1$ for the second equation. Since $a$ cannot be be equal to $1$ and equal to $1$ at the same time, this means that $a=-2$ and $a\neq 1$ will ensure that we have no solution.

iii) Since this imples we will eventually get to RREF, this means that $a-2 \neq 0$, $a^2+a-2 \neq 0$ or $a\neq 2,1,-2$ for unique solutions.

Can someone tell me if my process is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process is almost correct.
(i) You must show that $a=2$ does not meet the requirement.

(ii) $a=2$ is in this case.

(iii) You are right.